# How do I access a file with Weblogic?

Tags: java, file, weblogic

I need to access a file for some data in weblogic. I have this in my code,

```
File file = new File("myfile.csv");
```

When I run the code I get "File Not Found" error.

Where is the code actually looking for the file? I placed the code in a few different locations, but I cant get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is at the root of your application's classpath, you can use `getClass().getResource("myfile.csv");`.  If it's within a subdirectory, provide that path information in addition to the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path to access the file.  For example "/usr/local/blah/myfile.csv"

Answer (score 0):

The current directory for a running WebLogic Server instance is typically the root directory of the domain.

This is the parent directory under which you can find the 'config' and 'servers' subdirectories.